# What settings in Mac OS X affect the `Locale` and `Calendar` inside Java?

Tags: java, macos, calendar, dayofweek, week-number

These two questions prompted me to wonder what settings in Mac OS X affect the [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) defaults and behavior in Java:

- [WEEK_OF_YEAR inconsistent on different machines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24828014/642706)
- [Why would Calendar.getInstance() fail to use the default locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24842731/642706)

Key in those discussions are these two properties in Calendar:

- [firstDayOfWeek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek--)
- [minimalDaysInFirstWeek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek--)

The default for both those values is `1` in Java 7 & 8 when run on a default United States. What can cause other values to be reported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen some peculiar behavior as to what affects these properties of java.util.Calendar.

## Conclusions

The facts determined:

- The Java `Locale` is determined by *Language* in System Preferences.
- The two properties of Calendar are not affected by the Java Locale changed via the Mac’s *Language*. Instead they are determined by choosing a *Region* in System Preferences.
- Oddly enough, and possibly a bug, manually choosing *First day of week* popup menu in System Preferences fails to affect the equivalent property in Java. Affecting that Mac setting as part of choosing *Region* affects Java, yet manually choosing the popup menu does not.
- Setting the Java Locale via the Mac *Language* setting does not affect the Calendar's properties, yet passing a Locale to the Calendar's constructor *does* affect its properties (an apparent contradiction).

## Details

Running this code as a test.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TestCalendar
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime( new Date( new Long( 1293840000000l ) ) );  // First moment of the year 2011 in UTC.
        System.out.println( "Locale: " + locale + " | FirstDayOfWeek: " + c.getFirstDayOfWeek() + " | MinimialDaysInFirstWeek: " + c.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() );
    }
}
```

Using Mac OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) in a Parallels 9 virtual machine hosted on Mac OS X (Mavericks) with Java 8 Update 11 with a *United States* locale chosen during installation of the OS, I played around with `System Preferences` > `Language & Text`.

[image: Screen shot of window after choosing Apple menu > System Preferences > Language & Text in Mac OS X Mountain Lion]

## System Preferences > Language & Text > Region > First day of week

Strangely, changing `First day of week` on the *Region* tab has no effect. Java reports `FirstDayOfWeek: 1` whether I set that popup menu to "Sunday" or "Monday".

```
Locale: en_US | FirstDayOfWeek: 1 | MinimialDaysInFirstWeek: 1
```

Restarting the NetBeans IDE does not help. Restarting the Mac (virtual machine) does not help.

## System Preferences > Language & Text > Region

On the *Region* tab, check the *Show all regions* checkbox to see many more regions. Choose `French` > `France`. Run the IDE immediately. No need no restart the IDE or the OS, nor even to close the *System Preferences* window.

```
Locale: en_US | FirstDayOfWeek: 2 | MinimialDaysInFirstWeek: 4
```

Interesting on two accounts.

- Now we know the *Region* setting affects both of these key Calendar settings, yet the *Locale* has not changed. The value `2` as FirstDayOfWeek means `Monday`, as is correct for France (and much of the world).
- The other issue is bizarre, perhaps a bug: The *First day of week* popup seems to affect Java when set as part of a larger Region change but manually selecting that popup does not affect the Java properties in question.

Resetting the *Region* popup back to `United States` restores the Java properties, which is consistent and expected:

```
Locale: en_US | FirstDayOfWeek: 1 | MinimialDaysInFirstWeek: 1
```

## System Preferences > Language & Text > Language

On the *Language* tab, drag `Français` (French) to the top of the list, so it appears before English.

Immediately run the IDE.

```
Locale: fr_FR | FirstDayOfWeek: 1 | MinimialDaysInFirstWeek: 1
```

Again, interesting. Now we know the Java *Locale* is determined by the Mac *Language* setting. And we know that has no effect on the Calendar properties in question.

So you think Mac *Language* determines Java Locale, and Java Locale does *not* affect the Calendar properties? Right, when reading above, but Wrong when reading on to next section where we see that Java Locale set another way *can* affect the Calendar properties. Very confusing.

## Pass Java Locale

Another contradiction found. Let's restore the Mac back to US defaults: (1) English at top of *Language* list, (2) Region set to *United States*.

Change our code to pass a Locale to the Calendar's constructor.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance( Locale.FRANCE );
```

This affects the Calendar properties:

```
FirstDayOfWeek: 2 | MinimialDaysInFirstWeek: 4
```

So, the confusing contradiction is:

- Setting the Java Locale via the Mac's *Language* does *not* affect the Calendar's properties.
- Explicitly passing the Locale to the Calendar constructor *does* affect its properties.

Comment: Basil, you're so dedicated and meticulous, it's even scary! I've discovered my Region was set to UK - though I've no idea how that happened! - and setting it to US certainly had the effec you've discovered!

Comment: I'm trying to set java.util.Calendar to firstDayOfWeek=1, and no luck. It's always=2 Using Apple Java 1.6

Comment: @Sergey Never use the terrible `Calendar` class. Supplanted by the *java.time.* classes. See `WeekFields` class.