# pyspark doesn't recognize MMM dateFormat pattern in spark.read.load() for dates like 1989Dec31 and 31Dec1989

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, date-formatting

I'm facing a very strange issue with `pyspark` **on macOS Sierra**. My goal is to parse dates in `ddMMMyyyy` format (eg: `31Dec1989`) but get errors. I run Spark 2.0.1, Python 2.7.10 and Java 1.8.0_101. I tried also using Anaconda 4.2.0 (it ships with Python 2.7.12), but get errors too.

The same code on Ubuntu Server 15.04 with same Java version and Python 2.7.9 works without any error.

The [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat) about `spark.read.load()` states:

> **`dateFormat`** – sets the string that indicates a date format. Custom date
>   formats follow the formats at `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. This applies
>   to date type. If None is set, it uses the default value value,
>   `yyyy-MM-dd`.

The [official Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) talks about `MMM` as the right format to parse month names like `Jan`, `Dec`, etc. but it throws a lot of errors starting with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.
The documentation states that `LLL` can be used too, but `pyspark` doesn't recognize it and throws `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Illegal pattern component: LLL'`.

I know of another solution to `dateFormat`, but this is the fastest way to parse data and the simplest to code. What am I missing here?

In order to run the following examples you simply have to place `test.csv` and `test.py` in the same directory, then run `<spark-bin-directory>/spark-submit <working-directory>/test.py`.

### My test case using `ddMMMyyyy` format

I have a plain-text file named `test.csv` containing the following two lines:

```
col1
31Dec1989
```

and the code is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("My app") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

struct = StructType([StructField("column", DateType())])
df = spark.read.load(   "test.csv", \
                            schema=struct, \
                            format="csv", \
                            sep=",", \
                            header="true", \
                            dateFormat="ddMMMyyyy", \
                            mode="FAILFAST")
df.show()
```

I get errors. I tried also moving month name before or after days and year (eg: `1989Dec31` and `yyyyMMMdd`) without success.

### A working example using `ddMMyyyy` format

This example is identical to the previous one except from the date format. `test.csv` now contains:

```
col1
31121989
```

The following code prints the content of `test.csv`:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("My app") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

struct = StructType([StructField("column", DateType())])
df = spark.read.load(   "test.csv", \
                            schema=struct, \
                            format="csv", \
                            sep=",", \
                            header="true", \
                            dateFormat="ddMMyyyy", \
                            mode="FAILFAST")
df.show()
```

The ouput is the following (I omit the various verbose lines):

```
+----------+
|    column|
+----------+
|1989-12-31|
+----------+
```

---

> **UPDATE1**

I made a simple Java class that uses `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;

class testSimpleDateFormat 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMdd");
        String dateString = "1989Dec31";

        try {
            Date parsed = format.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(parsed.toString());
        }
        catch(ParseException pe) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot parse \"" + dateString + "\"");
        }       
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work on my environment and throws this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1989Dec31"
```

but works perfectly on another system (Ubuntu 15.04). This seems a Java issue, but I don't know how to solve it. I installed the latest available version of Java and all of my software has been updated.

Any ideas?

---

> **UPDATE2**

I've found how to make it work under pure Java by specifying `Locale.US`:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;

class HelloWorldApp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMdd", Locale.US);
        String dateString = "1989Dec31";

        try {
            Date parsed = format.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(parsed.toString());
        }
        catch(ParseException pe) {
            System.out.println(pe);
            System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot parse \"" + dateString + "\"");
        }       
    }
}
```

Now, the question becomes: **how to specify Java's Locale in `pyspark`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably worth noting that this was resolved on the [Spark mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg58402.html) on 24 Oct 2016. Per the original poster:

> This worked without setting other options: `spark/bin/spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.language=en" test.py`

and was reported as [SPARK-18076](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18076) (Fix default Locale used in DateFormat, NumberFormat to Locale.US) against Spark 2.0.1 and was resolved in Spark 2.1.0.

Additionally, while the above workaround (passing in `--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.language=en"`) for the specific issue the submitter raised is no longer needed if using Spark 2.1.0, a notable side-effect is that for Spark 2.1.0 users, you can no longer pass in something like `--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.language=fr"` if you wanted to parse a non-English date, e.g. "31mai1989".

In fact, as of Spark 2.1.0, when using `spark.read()` to load a csv, I think it's no longer possible to use the `dateFormat` option to parse a date such as "31mai1989", even if your default locale is French. I went as far as changing the default region and language in my OS to French and passed in just about every locale setting permutation I could think of, i.e.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR -Duser.region=FR" \
JAVA_ARGS="-Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR -Duser.region=FR" \
LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 \
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.country=FR -Duser.language=fr -Duser.region=FR" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.country=FR -Duser.language=fr -Duser.region=FR" \
test.py
```

to no avail, resulting in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:137)
```

But again, this only affects parsing non-English dates in Spark 2.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

You have already identified the issue as one of locale in the Spark's JVM. You can check the default country and language settings that are used by your Spark's JVM by going to http://localhost:4040/environment/ after launching the spark shell. Search for "user.language" and user.country" under System Properties section. It should be **US** and **en**.

You can change them like this, if needed.

Option 1:  Edit the spark-defaults.conf file in {SPARK_HOME}/conf folder. Add the following settings:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
```

Option 2: Pass the options to pyspark as a command line option

```
  $pyspark  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en" spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en"
```

Option 3: Change the language and region in your Mac OS. For example - [What settings in Mac OS X affect the `Locale` and `Calendar` inside Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844982/what-settings-in-mac-os-x-affect-the-locale-and-calendar-inside-java)

P.S. - I have only verified that Option 1 works. I have not tried out the other 2. More details about Spark configuration are here - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but I'd give the following a try:

```
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles"

--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles"
```